# Loss values above 1.0

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, train, cross-entropy, stochastic-gradient-descent

I have a convolutional neural network for tensors classification in Pytorch. I am using Cross-Entropy Loss. My optimizer is Stochastic Gradient Descent and the learning rate is 0.0001. The accuracy of both train and test sets seems to work fine. However, the loss values are above 1. Is there any idea why this is happening and how I can prevent this?

Here are the figures of the accuracies and the loss values:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many classes do you have?

Comment: Arya’s comment is spot-on. Cross entropy doesn't express a part of a whole, so a value exceeding 1 isn’t inherently suspect.

Comment: Moreover, on your plots loss didn’t stop decreasing at epoch 50, why not training further?

Comment: Thank you for your comments AryaMcCarthy, @Sycorax, and Tim. I have 30 classes and adding more epochs does not improve the situation. However, I've found the solution and now post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind generating unreasonable loss values, in this case, is the use of the final Softmax layer and Cross-Entropy Loss together.
So I just removed the Softmax layer and used a fully connected layer as the last layer in my CNN architecture and the problem was solved.

I've found my answer in the following links:

[Should I use softmax as output when using cross entropy loss in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55675345/should-i-use-softmax-as-output-when-using-cross-entropy-loss-in-pytorch)

[Can softmax be used with cross entropy?](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/39bo7k/can_softmax_be_used_with_cross_entropy/)